# Return a function from within a function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is what I tried:

```
var app = function() {
    var listen; 
    return listen = function()
        { 
            return "ggg";
        }
    }

console.log("dd: " + app().listen().length);
```

This says listen is not a function.
`console.log("dd: " + app().listen().length);`

Now w.r.t socket.io, we can write:

```
  const express = require('express');
  const app = express();
  app.listen();
```

I want to understand how to write like socket.io where from we can call one function from another?

Comment: Things like the Express initialization return *objects* with many methods; `listen()` is just one of them. Your function returns only that single function not wrapped in an object, so there's no place for a "listen" property to be. So `app()()` in your code would return `"ggg"`.

Comment: (Because somebody will point it out eventually, yes the function itself *could* have a "listen" property. It doesn't in the posted code.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want to create a [factory function](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-factory-functions/). The problem is that you are calling it's result as if it were an Object (with method `listen`). The way you created the function `app` returns a (named) function. See the snippet

```js
const app = function() {
  return listen = function() {
    return "ggg";
  };
}

const appFactory = function() {
  return {
    listen() {
      return "ggg";
    }
  };
}

// your function returns a function
console.log("dd: " + app()() + 
  ` => the returned function name is '${app().name}'`);

// the factory returns an object
// with method 'listen'
console.log("dd: " + appFactory().listen());
```

Comment: Many thanks for the helpful link and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning an expression which returns a value which is not object as somevar = 'somevalue' will give you 'somevalue'. instead you should

```
    return {
listen: function()
            { 
                return "ggg";
            }
    }
```

Comment: "_as somevar = 'somevalue' will give you undefined_" - [No it doesn't](https://jsfiddle.net/8wvyeumL/1/).